# pm.max_children limit for deploying wordpress app on aws ec2 free tier instance

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a wordpress application running using nginx and php5-fpm on ec2 free-tier instance. The application is showing error because of

```
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:11] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:11] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:11] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 13665
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:11] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:11] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[02-Dec-2016 06:35:16] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
```

My php-fpm configuration(/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf)
 is:

```
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

Nginx logs:

```
[error] 13607#0: *37345 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 191.96.249.80, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"
```

I have to restart php-fpm everytime to make the application running. I found some solutions on same problem but none of them helped.

Comment: This is not nginx issue. Raise pm.max_children limit, then monitor load average / memory / CPU.

Comment: I tried raising pm.max_children limit to 20 , but the problem persists.

Comment: I am new here. I don't know why people have down voted my question and not answering it. Is there anything I can change to get better response ?.

Comment: You're asking about PHP in nginx topic - wrong! You need adjust PHP-FPM settings, something like this: https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/determining-the-correct-number-of-child-processes-for-php-fpm-on-nginx